# How to search for a value in nested object and retrieve a parent value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iterator

I have an array of nested objects, one of which looks like this (I've condensed the full object as it would be too large, `jsonArr[0].data` is where the objects will be):

```
var jsonArr =  {
"data": [{
  "id": 5201,
  "name": "Simple Engineering",
  "contracts": [{
    "id": 461,
    "contract_type_id": 99,
    "contract_status_id": null,
    "pivot": {
        "entity_id": 5201,
        "contract_id": 461
    },
    "projects": [{
        "id": 2785,
        "name": "Something Hydro",
        "pivot": {
            "contract_id": 461,
            "project_id": 2785
        }
     }]
   }]
 }]
}
```

I have another array of values:

```
 var ids = [461,452,478,655]
```

I am trying to figure out a way to match the values in `ids` to the values at `data.contracts.id`. If a value matches, then I want to retrieve `data.name` and `projects.id`.

So in this case, the result would be an array like below as only `461` matches:

```
 var names = ["Simple Engineering",2785]
```

I hope this makes sense. As I am working with an array of several objects like the one above, I need a way that iterates over each `ids` value and each array object. Thanks, I appreciate any help.

Comment: The provided data structure is broken ... either `jsonArr` is an object then the code has to be written ... `const jsonArr =  { "data":  [ /* ... */ ] };` or it indeed is an array then the base structure needs to be like ... `const jsonArr = [ { "data":  [ /* ... */ ] }, { "data":  [ /* ... */ ] } /* ,.. */ ];`. To the OP, which structure one actually is dealing with?

Comment: btw ... there is nothing like a JSON array or a JSON object. JSON is a string based data exchange format. What the OP did provide is the invalid attempt of a nested object literal (syntax).

Comment: 3rd ... is the OP looking for a generic approach?.. Cause from the provided example and the matching value of `461` not only the `id` of a `contracts` item does match but the OP also wants to match `contract_id` from a `projects` item's `pivot` whereas a `projects` item's own `id` does not necessarily need to match.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I have edited my example data. It is supposed to be an object.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand what you mean by a generic approach?

Answer (score -1):

```js
var jsonArr =  {
"data": [{
  "id": 5201,
  "name": "Simple Engineering",
  "contracts": [{
    "id": 461,
    "contract_type_id": 99,
    "contract_status_id": null,
    "pivot": {
        "entity_id": 5201,
        "contract_id": 461
    },
    "projects": [{
        "id": 2785,
        "name": "Something Hydro",
        "pivot": {
            "contract_id": 461,
            "project_id": 2785
        }
     }]
   }]
 }]
}
var ids = [461,452,478,655]
var names=[]
var matched = jsonArr.data?.map(d=>d?.contracts?.map(con=>con?.projects?.map(proj=>{
   if(proj?.pivot?.contract_id===ids.find(id=>id===proj?.pivot?.contract_id))
   {
    names.push(d?.name)
    names.push(proj?.pivot?.project_id)
   }     
})))
console.log(names)
```

```
var names=[]
var matched = jsonArr.map(jArr=>jArr?.data?.map(d=>d?.contracts?.map(con=>con?.projects?.map(proj=>{
   if(proj?.pivot?.contract_id===ids.find(id=>id===proj?.pivot?.contract_id))
   {
    names.push(d?.name)
    names.push(proj?.pivot?.project_id)
   }     
}))))
console.log(names)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider revising your answer to add an explanation about what is happening in this code so that both the asker and future readers can understand the context.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).